# delete javascript function for disable right click, still works though?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When creating my website I added some Javascript to disable people from right-clicking my images.  I want to remove this now.  When I delete the Javascript however the right-click is still disabled. Please help!

Here is the code:

```
<!--disable right click-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
return false;
}); 
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Even when I delete this code the images cannot be right clicked.  I've also tried clearing my cache.

Comment: Can you please give us a link to your website.

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache? :)

Comment: Try reloading using  `shift + F5`.

Comment: Right-click menu pops up on that site just fine for me. However, the code you posted is definitely still part of the page.

Comment: @Pointy I realized I had the wrong url.  Please check the edited url above.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2390330 the code you posted in this question is still part of the page; it's there if you do a "view source". In other words, you have not successfully deleted the code.

Comment: @user2390330 Right-click works fine for me :)

Comment: @Mikey I thought it did, but if you try it in (for example) the menu bar it doesn't.

Comment: The code is still there. You may not have uploaded the html file. Are you using any CDN?

Comment: @Pointy I think I just updated my page.  Can you please check it again?

Comment: Right click works now

Comment: @Pointy Really? It works for me and in the source the code is also gone.

Comment: I want the user to be able to save the image to the desktop.  It still doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: @user2390330 Are you 100% sure that the url is correct. It works for me all of the images are right-clickable.

Comment: The right click context menu shows. However, you have overlapping `divs` which lay on top of the image. This is the reason why you can't have the option of saving it to desktop.

Comment: @Mikey well it's gone from the "armadillo" page (now; it was there a minute ago), but if you click to another one it's there. It shows up towards the top of the page in "view source".

Comment: Yes, it's only on the 'armadillo' page.  Thanks for your help.  I'll look into my divs and see what is overlapping.

Comment: The issue is the `pointer-events:none` rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `pointer-events:none` for the image in the CSS for the element `#projectimagesarm`. Remove it and the image becomes downloadable.

Comment: ok I just removed "pointer-events:none".  Still doesn't seem to be working for me?

Comment: does it have to do with my z-index for my divs maybe?